# segmentation fault after memcpy and free

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, free, memcpy

I a new C programmer. I try to remove one element from a static array and copy the rest on a dynamic array. The program worked fine but after `free()` I get a segmentation fault. I think that the pointer `temp` is pointing to some memory on stack that's why I get segmentation fault (because I try to free something, which is not created by malloc). But the problem memcpy should copy from stack to heap, so that `temp` stays pointing on heap. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char name [6]={'a','m', 'i', 'n','f','e'};
    char *temp= (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
    memcpy(temp,name1,4);
    memcpy(temp+4,name1+5,1);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("%c\n",*temp);
        temp++;
    }
    free(temp);
}
```

Output of the program is: amine

Comment: Um, nowhere in this program do you call `free`, so it's not clear what you mean by "after free() i get a segmentation fault."

Comment: i added it now. It is located at the end of the code

Comment: `temp++` means you're not freeing the pointer you allocated.

Comment: Note that it is only safe to free the pointer value that was returned by `malloc()` or `calloc()` or `realloc()` — or a copy of it; it is not safe to return a pointer value that was not returned to you by one of the allocation functions.  There are functions such as [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html)
which return a pointer as if allocated by `malloc()`, and then you must arrange to free those pointers too.  But you can't free a pointer that points somewhere into the middle of a block of allocated memory and expect to get away with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
free(temp-i)
```

You increment temp in the loop. Hence you are not freeing the pointer you created.

A better approach would be

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    printf("%c\n",*(temp+i));
}
free(temp);
```

Comment: thank you. It works. But should i set each time the pointer at the beginning of the dynamic array  before freeing the dynamic memory???

Comment: If you modify the pointer value, yes. But Its better to leave the pointer value unchanged, see the alternative implementation mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
char name [6]={'a','m', 'i', 'n','f','e'};
```

Pay attention that this isn't a string for C because there isn't the terminator string character '\0' (so it's just an array of characters but not a string).

Moreover

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("%c\n",*temp);
        temp++;
    }
```

you are increasing your pointer (accessing to extern memory parts)
You have to write this

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%c", temp[i]);
    }
printf("\n");
```

Or better

```
printf("%s\n", temp);
```